Type checks doesn't work when importing my types from a custom library
so basically, I'm working on a react-native library which exports some components and utilities to improve overall development.
In this library, I have a light and dark Theme, which I want to be able to override in my app code. To make this easier and intuitive, I want to import the type definition of a Theme from my library.
These 2 files comes from my library :
**src/types/CustomTheme.ts
declare type CustomTheme = {
  dark: boolean;
  colors: {
    primary: string;
    background: string;
    card: string;
    text: string;
    textOnPrimary: string;
    border: string;
    variant: string;
    notification: string;
    inversed: string;
  };
  text: {
    lg: number;
    med: number;
    sm: number;
  };
};
export default CustomTheme;

**src/index.tsx
// Types for theme
import type CustomTheme from './types/CustomTheme';
export type { CustomTheme };

Then in my react-native app i'm doing :
import { type CustomTheme } from 'my-library';

let CustomLightTheme: CustomTheme = {
  // Here VScode doesn't tells me that 'CustomLightTheme' is missing a lot of properties
};

package.json
{
  "name": "mr-design",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "A react-native components library",
  "source": "./src/index.tsx",
  "main": "./lib/commonjs/index.js",
  "module": "./lib/module/index.js",
  "types": "./lib/typescript/src/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./lib/typescript/src/index.d.ts",
      "import": "./lib/module/index.js",
      "require": "./lib/commonjs/index.js"
    }
  },
..et
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "paths": {
      "mcomponents": [
        "./src/index"
      ]
    },
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noStrictGenericChecks": false,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
    "declaration": true
  }
}


My declaration files ('.d.ts') are located in './src/types/'
Even if there is no errors, type checking is not really done here. For example, VSCode is not telling that my object miss some properties.
How can i have these kind of type checks when importing a type from my library ?

As far as I see your code looks fine from the type declaration and usage PoV. I would suggest that you check your tsconfig.json file to check if its correctly working for type declarations. Refer to this and make any changes if  required
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",  //node module resolution, this is necesary for finding type defns in libs
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,  // for library to generate type declarations
    // other options...
  },
  "include": ["src"],  // include the source files
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "asdfasd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}

}

Make sure main and types fields point to the right locations where the compiled JS and type declaration files will be output.
After this, delete you node modules
rm -rf node_modules
install with the package manager that you use npm or yarn
and run
npx tsc

You're right. After building the library, my '.d.ts' files are not coorectly being added. Even after modifying my tsconfig, i couldn't manage to get it works. But, if i change my type files extension from '.d.ts' to '.ts', everything works fine. As i used the create-react-native-library template, and modified package and tsconfig files, i probably introduced this issue. I'll give more info about my config. Do you know if the issue could also comes from my 'package.json' ?

Yes, the .d.ts files not being generated might be due to the configuration in your package.json. I have updated my answer to include the package.json changes. make sure the main and types are pointing to the correct location
